# Computer hangs when using live USB to boot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, boot-loader, manjaro

I recently built a desktop/server at home and I am attempting to use Manjaro as the OS. However, when I insert the live usb with the Manjaro ISO on it, without fail, after reaching `[OK] Reached target sound card` the screen goes black and the monitor turns off and never receives a signal from the server again. When using other images it also hang at various points, such as with Ubuntu where it reaches a screen with no GUI and then the monitor receives no signal again.

The server's hardware is as follows:

- AMD Athlon 200GE 3.2 GHz Dual-Core Processor
- ASRock B450M PRO4 Micro ATX AM4 Motherboard
- G.Skill Ripjaws V Series 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-2400 Memory
- Western Digital Blue 500 GB M.2-2280 Solid State Drive
- EVGA BQ 600 W 80+ Bronze Certified Semi-modular ATX Power Supply

Using the `nomodeset` option has prevented stalling. Thanks to [K7AAY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49368/k7aay)
for the suggestion.

Comment: Please add _nomodeset_ to the GRUB2 command line by editing it during boot; are you able to boot then? Please click [edit] and let us know so we can proceed to the next step.